# Duplicate class error while generating pdf using separate class

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-jetifier

The duplicate class error. jetters are given true
This error is poppping even after trying all the methods available in the StackOverflow.

error is
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-15.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpb4c.png)

ComplaintDetailsFragment.java

```
package com.example.ecomplaint;

    import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Locale;
    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link ComplaintDetailsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class ComplaintDetailsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    
    
        // variables for our buttons.
        Button generatePDFbtn;
    
        // declaring width and height
        // for our PDF file.
        int pageHeight = 1120;
        int pagewidth = 792;
    
        // creating a bitmap variable
        // for storing our images
        Bitmap bmp, scaledbmp;
    
        // constant code for runtime permissions
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        com.example.ecomplaint.Complaint present;
    
        public ComplaintDetailsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        public ComplaintDetailsFragment(com.example.ecomplaint.Complaint present){
            this.present=present;
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ComplaintDetailsFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static ComplaintDetailsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            ComplaintDetailsFragment fragment = new ComplaintDetailsFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complaint_details, container, false);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    
            TextView title=view.findViewById(R.id.details_title);
            title.setText(present.getTitle());
    
            TextView name=view.findViewById(R.id.details_name);
            name.setText(present.getName());
    
            TextView regno=view.findViewById(R.id.details_regno);
            regno.setText(present.getRegno());
    
            TextView incident=view.findViewById(R.id.details_info);
            incident.setText(present.getIncident_info());
    
            TextView ComplaintFrom=view.findViewById(R.id.complaintFrom);
            ComplaintFrom.setText(present.getComplaintFrom().getName());
    
            TextView status=view.findViewById(R.id.details_status);
            status.setText(present.getStatus().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
    
    //        TextView expert=view.findViewById(R.id.details_expert);
    //        expert.setText("EComplaint");
    //        Button pdf=view.findViewById(R.id.printbtn);
    //        pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onClick(View v) {
    //                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PDF button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //            }
    //        });
            // initializing our variables.
            generatePDFbtn = view.findViewById(R.id.printbtn);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_pdf1);
            scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 140, 140, false);
    
            // below code is used for
            // checking our permissions.
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
    
            generatePDFbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // calling method to
                    // generate our PDF file.
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PDF button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    generatePDF();
    //                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),generatePdf.class);
    //                startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    
    
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            Log.i("this",currentUser.getDisplayName());
    
            //HomeFragment.arrayList.clear();
            //HomeFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        private void generatePDF() {
            // creating an object variable
            // for our PDF document.
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    
            // two variables for paint "paint" is used
            // for drawing shapes and we will use "title"
            // for adding text in our PDF file.
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Paint title = new Paint();
    
            // we are adding page info to our PDF file
            // in which we will be passing our pageWidth,
            // pageHeight and number of pages and after that
            // we are calling it to create our PDF.
            PdfDocument.PageInfo mypageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pagewidth, pageHeight, 1).create();
    
            // below line is used for setting
            // start page for our PDF file.
            PdfDocument.Page myPage = pdfDocument.startPage(mypageInfo);
    
            // creating a variable for canvas
            // from our page of PDF.
            Canvas canvas = myPage.getCanvas();
    
            // below line is used to draw our image on our PDF file.
            // the first parameter of our drawbitmap method is
            // our bitmap
            // second parameter is position from left
            // third parameter is position from top and last
            // one is our variable for paint.
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 56, 40, paint);
    
            // below line is used for adding typeface for
            // our text which we will be adding in our PDF file.
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
    
            // below line is used for setting text size
            // which we will be displaying in our PDF file.
            title.setTextSize(15);
    
            // below line is sued for setting color
            // of our text inside our PDF file.
            title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.purple_200));
    
            // below line is used to draw text in our PDF file.
            // the first parameter is our text, second parameter
            // is position from start, third parameter is position from top
            // and then we are passing our variable of paint which is title.
            canvas.drawText("Register your complaints easily online!", 209, 100, title);
            canvas.drawText("EComplaint", 209, 80, title);
    
            // similarly we are creating another text and in this
            // we are aligning this text to center of our PDF file.
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
            title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.purple_200));
            title.setTextSize(15);
    
            // below line is used for setting
            // our text to center of PDF.
            title.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("Complaint details:", 396, 560, title);
    
            canvas.drawText("Title: "+present.getTitle(), 396, 580, title);
            canvas.drawText("Address: "+present.getName(), 396, 600, title);
            canvas.drawText("Phone Number: "+present.getRegno(), 396, 620, title);
            canvas.drawText("Complaint Details: "+present.getIncident_info(), 396, 640, title);
            canvas.drawText("Registered By: "+present.getComplaintFrom().getName(), 396, 660, title);
            canvas.drawText("Status: "+present.getStatus().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT), 396, 680, title);
    
    
            pdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);
    
            // below line is used to set the name of
            // our PDF file and its path.
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "YourComplaint.pdf");
    
            try {
                // after creating a file name we will
                // write our PDF file to that location.
                pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
    
                // below line is to print toast message
                // on completion of PDF generation.
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PDF file generated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // below line is used
                // to handle error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // after storing our pdf to that
            // location we are closing our PDF file.
            pdfDocument.close();
        }
    
        private boolean checkPermission() {
            // checking of permissions.
            int permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int permission2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return permission1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    
        private void requestPermission() {
            // requesting permissions if not provided.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
    
                    // after requesting permissions we are showing
       

             // users a toast message of permission granted.
                boolean writeStorage = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean readStorage = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (writeStorage && readStorage) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Granted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradel files

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

    }
    dependencies {

        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module level gradel

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ecomplaint"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains' , module:'annotations'
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.2'
    implementation 'itext:itext:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

[Code link](https://github.com/Keerthishankar-Punchithaya/EComplaint/tree/generatepdf)

[original project](https://github.com/Keerthishankar-Punchithaya/EComplaint)

Comment: Use IntelliJ IDEA [**Dependency Analyzer**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#dependency_analyzer) to find out from which dependencies these duplicated `org.jetbrains:annotations` libraries come.